# How to Authenticate my user using email and password?

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, azure-storage

The title is basically what I need, I have been trying for ages doing that without any success. I have this Azure Function App, where I'm trying to authenticate my user by email and password:

```
 [FunctionName(nameof(Auth))]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Auth(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Admin, "POST", Route = "auth")] HttpRequest req,
            [Table("User", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] TableClient tdClient,
            ILogger log)
        {
            string url = String.Format("http://localhost:7235/api/");

            HttpMessageHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
            {
            };

            var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler)
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri(url),
                Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0)
            };

            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ContentType", "application/json");

            var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("roy.mitchel@somecompany.com:pass1234");
            string val = System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + val);


            HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.GetAsync(url).Result;
            return new OkObjectResult(response);
        }
```

If someone could help me with that, would be amazing, my users are stored in Azure Table. What I basically need is inser the email and password of a user, and retrieve all the details.

```
{
    "version": "1.1",
    "content": {
        "headers": [
            {
                "key": "Content-Length",
                "value": [
                    "0"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "statusCode": 404,
    "reasonPhrase": "Not Found",
    "headers": [
        {
            "key": "Date",
            "value": [
                "Thu, 01 Sep 2022 23:54:07 GMT"
            ]
        },
        {
            "key": "Server",
            "value": [
                "Kestrel"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "trailingHeaders": [],
    "requestMessage": {
        "version": "1.1",
        "versionPolicy": 0,
        "content": null,
        "method": {
            "method": "GET"
        },
        "requestUri": "http://localhost:7235/api/",
        "headers": [
            {
                "key": "ContentType",
                "value": [
                    "application/json"
                ]
            },
            {
                "key": "Authorization",
                "value": [
                    "Bearer cm95Lm1pdGNoZWxAc29tZWNvbXBhbnkuY29tOnBhc3MxMjM0"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "properties": {},
        "options": {}
    },
    "isSuccessStatusCode": false
}
```

This is what I get when I call the API.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question, you just need to replace "Bearer" with "basic".

Comment: I did that, my problem here is I'm not able to retrieve the details from my user from the database.

Comment: what do you get on response object, can we have an example of that?

Comment: I have edited my post with the response.